# Make a scrollbar on Tkinter

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tkinter, scrollbar

I need a scrollbar to roll under the elements, see that when create more than 30 elements from first window the screen dont fill in correct mode:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import tkSimpleDialog
from matplotlib import pylab

prefixo = "vetor"


def makeWidgets():
    global entries
    window = Tk()

    window.title('Vetores')
    form = Frame(window)
    form.pack()
    entries = {}
    numero = tkSimpleDialog.askinteger("Vetores", "Digite o numero de vetores a serem usados:")

    for ix in range(numero):
        label = "%s %s" % (prefixo , ix + 1)
        lab = Label(form, text=label)
        ent = Entry(form)
        lab.grid(row=ix, column=0)
        ent.grid(row=ix, column=1)
        entries[label] = ent

    Button(window, text="Histograma",  command=histograma).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(window, text="Media",  command=media).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(window, text="Mediana", command=mediana).pack(side=LEFT)    
    window.mainloop()

    def pegavalores():
        valores = []
        for chave, entrada in sorted(entries.items()):
            valores.append(entrada.get())
        valores = np.asarray(valores, dtype=np.float64)
        return valores

    def histograma():
        histograma = pegavalores()
        pylab.grid(True)  
        plt.hist(histograma)
        plt.show()

    def media():
        media = pegavalores()
        elementos = len(media)
        valormedio = np.sum(media)/elementos
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Media", valormedio)

    def mediana():
        mediana = pegavalores()
        resultado = np.median(mediana)
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Mediana", resultado)

window = makeWidgets()
```

Comment: You can use `grid_forget()` to make the top elements invisible and use Scrollbars `command` to actualize the view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Scrollbar widget (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm). 
Unfortunately it doesn’t work pretty straight forward with frames. When I was working with Tkinter I found this extension quite useful:

http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/VerticalScrolledFrame

If you include it in your script it is easy to put your widgets in the interior frame to get the vertical scrollbar like:

```
window.title('Vetores')
form = VerticalScrolledFrame(window)
form.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
entries = {}
numero = tkSimpleDialog.askinteger("Vetores", "Digite o numero de vetores a serem usados:")

for ix in range(numero):
    label = "%s %s" % (prefixo , ix + 1)
    lab = Label(form.interior, text=label)
    ent = Entry(form.interior) ...
```